# insert Element into two Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am creating table and populate it into two divs, first div is in small size and second one for large view , other graphs works fine but element not working, its populate the last div. as you can see the code and [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4TZtX/) here.

```
$("#sample").empty()
$("#fulls").empty()
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.className="report";
var first = table.insertRow(0);
first.className= "headerTable";
var h1 = first.insertCell(0);
var h2 = first.insertCell(1);
var h3 = first.insertCell(2);
var h4 = first.insertCell(3);
var h5 = first.insertCell(4);

h1.className= "headerTable";
h2.className= "headerTable";
h3.className= "headerTable";
h4.className= "headerTable";
h5.className= "headerTable";

h1.innerHTML = ("Speed");
h2.innerHTML = ("RPM");
h3.innerHTML =("Acc");
h4.innerHTML = ("Brake");
h5.innerHTML =("Dated");
for (var i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    var first = table.insertRow((i+1));
    first.className= "tableRow";
    var h1 = first.insertCell(0);
    var h2 = first.insertCell(1);
    var h3 = first.insertCell(2);
    var h4 = first.insertCell(3);
    var h5 = first.insertCell(4);
    h1.innerHTML = i;
    h2.innerHTML = i;
    h3.innerHTML = i;
    h4.innerHTML = i;
    h5.innerHTML= new Date();
}
$("#fulls").html(table);
$("#sample").html(table);
```

and i tried with javascript but same result

```
document.getElementById("fulls").innerHTML = table;
document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = table;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't insert an element in 2 containers, you need to clone it like

```
$("#fulls").html($(table).clone()); 
//or use cloneNode() like $("#fulls").html(table.cloneNode(true));
$("#sample").html(table);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sTyMQ/)

When you append the same element instance to 2 containers, it is removed from first one and is added to the second one, so if you want to keep a copy in both the places you need to clone that element.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
$("#fulls").html(table);
$("#sample").html($("#fulls").html());
```

The problem was because you had only one `table` object used in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would require something like this

```
var th = document.createElement('th');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.className = "report";

th.appendChild(img);
tr.appendChild(th);
tbody.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(tbody);
```