# What's the difference between .clone() and .html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between Jquery's .clone() and .html() functions?

Jquery documentation states:

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes.
>
> In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any
>   element. If the selector expression matches more than one element,
>   only the first match will have its HTML content returned.

To me these seem to interchangeable, so are there specific situation where one would be used of the other?

Comment: Just based on the documentation alone - "deep copy of the set" versus "first match"

Comment: i have been stuck on .html() function to populate same content into two div . but i got the difference after i ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901198/insert-element-into-two-div

Comment: `.clone(true)` can copy handlers http://jsfiddle.net/Fw57V/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**`.clone()` returns a jQuery object while `.html()` returns a string.**

Use `.clone()` if you want a copy of the jQuery objects and use `.html()` to get the inner HTML of a jQuery object in a string format. Each method has its own purpose ([and cost](http://jsperf.com/jquery-clone-vs-html-construction)).

Also, as [sgroves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810899/sgroves) pointed out, "`.clone()` performs a deep copy of the **set of elements** found by the selector, while `.html()` only [uses] the **first** matched element."*

---

*Although note that `.html(newContent)` will set the inner HTML of a ***set*** of matched elements. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/J8sDS/)

*Another* note: the (generally) "faster" option is to use strings rather than jQuery objects when doing DOM manipulation ([JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-object-vs-string-injection)). Thus, I'd recommend `.html()` if all you need is text content. Again though: *each method has its own purpose*.

Comment: also according to the docs, `clone` performs a deep copy of the **set** of elements found by the selector (i assume it would return an array of jQuery objects in this case), while `html` only returns the contents of the first matched element.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a list of differences :

1. `.clone` can be used on multiple selected elements while `.html()` returns only the html of the first element.
2. `.clone` returns a jQuery object while `.html` returns a string.
3. `.clone` can (if specified) keep any **event and data** of the DOM element. `.html` will not.
4. `.clone` makes a copy of the selected element and all its descendents while `.html` only gets its descendents.  In other words, comparing to DOM methods, `.clone` is similar to .outerHTML and `.html` is more like .innerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

The clone() method will copy the data and events associated with the DOM elements that are copied, this method returns a jQuery object of the target.  html() is just the string representation of the DOM, which means that none of the events/data associated with that portion of the DOM will be copied, this method returns just a string.

**Edit #2**
Removed my comments about clone() being just as fast as html(), it is actually slower.  Examples can be seen below in Casey Falk's comments.

Comment: Your JSPerf is too bloated. Try a simple test: http://jsperf.com/jquery-clone-vs-html-construction

Comment: True, that it is more bloated, but you are typically not just running .html() or .clone() by itself.  The actual call of .html() is considerably faster, but if you re-insert that into the DOM, the DOM has to be recreated, which will take a considerably amount of time and clone gains back what it gave up in performance initially.  I'll note that in the answer though since it probably should be stated.

Comment: Nope. The DOM still must be "created" for both -- or more accurately, *changed*. I would be willing to bet that inserting a jQuery object is slower than just Inserting innerHTML, but lemme make a JSPerf and get back to you on that. : ) The point of a speed test is to *isolate* some aspect of your code -- not say "oh, but you never do it by itself anyway." ;) Lemme get back to you on that Perf when I get some dinner in me, haha.

Comment: **Yuppers: string-insertions are faster than jQuery object-insertions** (http://jsperf.com/jquery-object-vs-string-injection). Feel free to play around of course; it's possible there are instances where they are not. Note that this makes sense however since (if I recall) jQuery creates the string to insert *from* the jQuery object before any DOM changes take place. So really, we're skipping the middle man. :)

Comment: Oh, nice.  Thanks for following up on that, not sure why I just assumed that inserting a jQuery object would be faster, but I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

from the quoted sentences you posted above the answer is there:

`.clone()`it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes. means it select all the elements within the selector.

while `.html()` it only selects the first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='rating-stars'>
                <ul id='stars'>
                    <li class='star' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
                        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class='star' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
                        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class='star' title='Good' data-value='3'>
                        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class='star' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
                        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class='star' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
                        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
.clone() can also we used in cases where we need to use a piece of code multiple times on out html page. Say we need to include the above code to create star rating multiple times.    
So in this case if we want this same code to be applied multiple times in out html , we can use two ways:-
```

1. var ratingStar = $('.rating-stars').html();
2. var ratingStar = $('.rating-stars').clone();

Advantage of using .clone() is that all the styles applied to the elements in .rating-stars will be present as .clone() give back a jquery object while .html() will simply return an string with no styles attached.