# How to add the same elements dynamically when on #addRow is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add elements dynamically. I'm not getting how to do this.

Same element row should be appended.

```
<div class="schedulingRecord">
    <div class="form-group pi-col-md-12 pi-margin-bottom-10">
        <div class="day-time pi-margin-bottom-10">
            <select class="form-control" style="padding:5px; width:100px; height: auto; font-size:13px; margin-right:20px;" name="day">
                <option>Sunday</option>
            </select> 
            <select class="form-control" style="padding:5px; width:55px; height: auto; font-size:13px; margin-right:5px;" name="startTime">
                <option>06</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" style="padding:5px; width:55px; height: auto; font-size:13px; margin-right:5px;" name="startTimeCon">
                <option selected>AM</option>
                <option>PM</option>
            </select>to 
            <select class="form-control" style="padding:5px; width:55px; height: auto; font-size:13px; margin-right:5px;" name="endTime">
                <option>08</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" style="padding:5px; width:55px; height: auto; font-size:13px; margin-right:20px;"name="endTimeCon">
                <option>AM</option>
                <option selected>PM</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" style="padding:5px; width:70px; height: auto; font-size:13px; margin-right:5px;" name="timezone">
                <option>IST</option>
            </select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pi-pull-right deleteRecord"><img src="images/delete-icon.png" alt="" title="Remove"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pi-pull-right addRecord" id="addRow">
    <img src="images/add-icon.png" alt="" title="Add New" style="position:relative; top:-1px; right:4px;"/>
</a>
```

Comment: You can do it by using JavaScript. Maybe using jQuery as well.

Comment: Do you want to append the same fields into your page?

Comment: What is `#addRow` and where is `same element row`?

Comment: @ekad take a look at edited question for `#addRow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This Code**:  **[Working Code Here in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/ye4dd4fa/1/)**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addRow();" class="pi-pull-right addRecord" id="addRow">
    <img src="images/add-icon.png" alt="" title="Add New" style="position:relative; top:-1px; right:4px;"/> click
</a>
```

**JSCode**

```
function addRow(){   
    $('.schedulingRecord').append($('.form-group').html());    
}
```

- Deletion Code -

`function deleteRow(curDelete){

    $(curDelete).closest('div').closest('div').remove();
}`

- Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add a `Html` and get all the inside HTML contents using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) functions

  - See the Code for Deletion [JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/ye4dd4fa/4/)

Comment: @Parag122 -  Accept the answer will helps others to find out correct solutions. Glad to help you :)

Comment: There are many answers in SO with text "use this code" or even "you must use this code", but without any explanation. Yes, this question should be closed just because it is about "write code for me, because I want something, but don't care to try to do it myself". But at least links to `.append()`, `.html()` and jQuery's selectors will be helpful.

Comment: @Regent - agree with you

Comment: @Prog - thank u, can u help out with deleting records too.I want to delete corresponding records if $(.deleteRecord) is clicked. I m new to this. I m not getting it.

Comment: @Parag122 - sure i'll help you - i'll update answer in 5 min.

Comment: @Prog yes, are you ready to write code for elements deletion? :) And then for calculating time, for showing image/text based on time, for handling top menu, for saving selected date in localStorage and whatever else?

Comment: @Parag122 - See the updated Fiddle for Deletion :) http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/ye4dd4fa/4/

Comment: @prog during add can i add index to child node?

Answer (score 2):

Use [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
$(".addRecord").on("click", function(){
    $(".form-group:first").clone(true).appendTo(".schedulingRecord");    
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjw87w0w/)**

You could also use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) but, here are a few differences:

1. `.clone` can be used on multiple element at the same time while `.html()` return only the html of the first element.
2. `.clone` return a jQuery object while `.html` return a string.
3. `.clone` can (if specified) keep any **event and data** of the DOM element. `.html` **cannot**.
4. `.clone` keep the root element while `.html` only get the innerHTML.

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24943102/1862225)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
  $('.form-group').append($('.day-time:first').html());
```

This is what you want I guess!
Thanks to Regent

Comment: Sorry! Thanks for the correction @Regent